# Instantly showing adView

Tags: android, caching, delay, ads, adview

My application got some "GameOver" activity which gets called when the game is over. This activity contains it's own AdView. Now my problem is, everytime the player loses the game and this activity gets called, it takes some time for the adview to laod. 
The problem is, the user can press on the restart button without even having seen the adView because it wasn't loaded. When pressing on the button another acitivty starts.
My solution now was a delay on the button --> the user has to wait 3 sec. to be able to press on the button. That's not good for the user, nobody likes to wait.

So is there any way to store the already used adView in the background while another activity gets called and load the adview when the gameOver activity gets called the next time?

What is the most efficient way to show ads without having to reload them on every activity?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

putting adView in **GAMEOVER** Activity is not good idea. Becuase user will not stay at that activity more then few seconds. As user will restart the game if he is interested  to play again Or else he will quit game but he will not stand for more time. So put the adView in the Activity which user stays For **MORE TIME**.

While adView always takes a time (Few seconds) to load Ad. As it will connect to internet And it will do process to load Adview. So i guess ther's no way to load adFaster. But instead you will change your Activity to Attract User Attention on Ad Where user stays For Much Time.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Only problem is that my MAIN game activity is almost fullscreen and there is no place for an ad on it... however, thanks for the reply!